# Change scoring type after the fact?

Tags: discussion, rules, editing

I made a [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) here: [Implement ROT-47... in ROT-47](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22751/implement-rot-47-in-rot-47)

However, I think my scoring rules are not servicing the job of the original question well. I am considering changing the question to a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), but it may be too late for me to change the scoring now that there are many valid answers.

Etiquette wise, is it too late? If I didn't want to risk stepping on site standard practices, I would have changed it to [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) already, but I know that at least one user edited their program a number of times to my silly scoring rules already.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was wise of you to voluntarily move it to Sandbox, and unwise to reactivate it before the kinks had been worked out. However, that ship has sailed, and it would be bad form to substantially alter the contest after there are valid answers. The challenge itself is interesting, even if the scoring is a mess.

*Edit: he's correct, he has a tiebreaker, so that's a non-issue.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Fwiw I already have a section on tie breakers, first tiebreaker = popularity contest, second tiebreaker = golf

Comment: In any event, I can chalk this up as a learning experience; I won't make this mistake again.